# How to find the difference between two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database ver 5.1. I have two tables **Table_A** will always keep the records in it. **Table_B** will be used to only compare the differences. Is there a MySQL query function via PHP that will compare the rows and tell me what rows are missing on **Table_B**.

**Table_A**

```
user    name
 1      bob
 1      joe
 1      sally
 1      matt
```

**Table_B**

```
user    name
 1      bob
 1      joe
 1      sally
 1      john
```

When the PHP query was run how would I compare **Table_A** vs **Table_B**?
All I need is to tell me that `matt` no longer exists and it will add `john` to **Table_A**.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM Table_A WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Table_B)
```

Comment: I switched user to name and it worked. Then I guess I would just run the query back words to insert any new names then.

Comment: Worked like a charm for both ways of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: Right, it should have been `name` - sorry and changed.