# How to compare two MySQL tables and print the difference between it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, "list1" and "list2" with the fields "id (PRIMARY A-I)", "name", "url". Everyday, people generates a new list with thousands of names and urls, and that I put it on "list2" table. But when they do that, I need to show what names and urls are not duplicated on the tables, is it possible?

I'm doing this using txt files "list1.txt" and "list2.txt" and doing the comparison with pure PHP, but I think MySQL can work faster than that.

So, how can I compare two tables on MySQL, showing the difference between it?

Example of lists using txt files

list1.txt

```
Maria:http://www.google.com.br
João:http://www.yahoo.com.br
Francisco:http://www.uol.com.br
Natália:http://www.terra.com.br
```

list2.txt

```
Maria:http://www.google.com.br
João:http://www.yahoo.com.br
Joana:http://www.facebook.com
Carlos:http://www.gvt.com.br
Natália:http://www.terra.com.br
```

Comment: Look over to the right under Related, there are many related links >>> This one for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403985/

Comment: @JayBlanchard There are so many, I didn't know which one to choose.

Comment: No, but it doesn't solve my problem, that's why I asked a new question, because if list1 has 1000 names and urls, and list2 has 1200, of course the new 200 registry is not present on list1, I need to know if that 1000 (present on list1 first), are still present on list2, even with new registrys of list2, and then list2 becomes list1, and this cicle will repeat everyday.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM List1 WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM List2) 
UNION 
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM List2 WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM List1)
```